# Vaadin flow Multiplatform Runtime update

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

After updating **mpr-v8 from 5.0.3 to 5.0.4** with update to **vaadin flow 21.0.1** the following code does not work anymore:

```
UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
```

> window is an instance of com.vaadin.ui.Window.

This worked before and opened the legacy window in flow context.

Was there some change on this behavior?

Comment: seems as if generally no legacy components are displayed anymore in flow context

Comment: seems as if a complete rebuild solved the problem

Comment: Problem reappears during testing - legacy components do not show up anymore

Comment: Seems related to this issue: https://github.com/vaadin/multiplatform-runtime/issues/60

Comment: switching back to mpr-v8 5.0.3 (overriding 5.0.4 from vaadin-bom) solves the problem as a workaround for now.